# Set DatePickerDialog Minimum and Maximum

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to validate `DatePickerDialog`. But user can not set birth date bigger than current date. I need the date to be neither less nor greater than today.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.ib_obtener_fecha:
                obtenerFecha();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void obtenerFecha(){
        final DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                final int mesActual = month + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth):String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(mesActual):String.valueOf(mesActual);
                date.setText(diaFormateado + BARRA + mesFormateado + BARRA + year);
            }
        },anio, mes, dia);
        recogerFecha.show();
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort.

Comment: And although your question got an answer (good one btw), you will likely get more help in the next one if you code is written in english as well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void obtenerFecha(){
        final DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                final int mesActual = month + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth):String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(mesActual):String.valueOf(mesActual);
                date.setText(diaFormateado + BARRA + mesFormateado + BARRA + year);
            }
        },anio, mes, dia);
        recogerFecha.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDateInMillis);
        recogerFecha.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDateInMillis);
        recogerFecha.show();
    }
```

Basically you access the DatePicker inside the DatePickerDialog and set its max date and min date.